# vectors: finding acceleration

Tags: vectors

A particle has velocity $3i-2j$ initially and velocity $5i+4j$  4 seconds later

here I tried to find the magnitude if its acceleration,assumed constant

acceleration=$\frac{change-in-velocity}{change-in-time}$

a=$\frac{\sqrt{(5^2+4^2)} -\sqrt{(3^2+2^2)}}{4}$

$\frac{\sqrt{41}-\sqrt{13}}{4}$

initial velocity (u)= $\sqrt{3^2+2^2}$ =$\sqrt{13}$

finally, the magnitude $s=ut+1/2at^2$

s= ($\sqrt{13}$ x 4) + (1/2 x  $\frac{\sqrt{41}-\sqrt{13}}{4}$ x 4^2)

s= 2($\sqrt{13}$+$\sqrt{41}$)

but I'm not sure about the final answer, if Anyone can help.. it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The acceleration is $a = {1 \over 4} (5 i + 4 j - (3 i - 2j)) = { 1\over 2 } (i+3j)$.

The magnitude is $\|a\| = {1 \over 2} \sqrt{1^2+3^2} = {\sqrt{10} \over 2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The average acceleration $\vec a$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
\vec a&=\frac{(\hat x 5+\hat y4)-(\hat x3-\hat y2)}{4}\\\\
&=\frac{\hat x 2+\hat y 6}{4}\\\\
&=\frac12(\hat x +\hat y 3)
\end{align}$$

The magnitude of acceleration is therefore

$$\begin{align}
|\vec a|&=\frac12 \sqrt{(1)^2+(3)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{10}
\end{align}$$